# Как заполнить Arraylist случайными цифрами?

Tags: java, arraylist

Мысленно отправляю плюсы в карму каждому, кто подскажет)

Итак, есть задача:

Создать 2 массива Arraylist по 7 цифр в каждом, а затем заполнить их случайными числами от 0 до 9 включительно.
После чего вывести эти два массива в консоль так, чтобы их числа были отсортированы - от большего к меньшему. Условный пример того, что нужно увидеть в консоли в итоге:

[0,2,5,6,7,8,9]

[0,1,1,5,6,7,9]

И вот, собственно, ключевой вопрос:

Как в коде ниже заполнить списки winningNumbers и playersNumbers случайными числами, а потом отсортировать их по возрастанию?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList winningNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList playersNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы сами уже пробовали написать какой-то код? Покажите, с какой конкретной трудностью вы столкнулись?

Comment: Спасибо за вопросы. Сразу увидел, где натупил и не разобрался в постановке задачи. 
Добавил код и убрал из вопроса intCollection (это слово из лекции, которое я воспринял, как ключевое).

Answer (score 2):

Приведённый код напоминает начало реализации некой лотереи, судя по названиям списков `playerNumbers, winningNumbers`, поэтому скорее всего дубликаты не должны допускаться в обоих списках.

Для генерации списков без дубликатов при помощи Stream API следует применить операцию `Stream::distinct` *перед* ограничением длины списка:

```java
public static List<Integer> randomList(int min, int maxIncl, int count) {
    return new Random() // или более непредсказуемый генератор SecureRandom()
        .ints(min, maxIncl + 1) // IntStream, значения [min, maxIncl]
        .distinct()     // уникальные значения (дубликаты исключены)
        .limit(count)   // ограничить длину списка
        .sorted()       // сортировать по возрастанию
        .boxed()        // Stream<Integer>
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // или toList() JDK 16+
}

List<Integer> winningNums = randomList(0, 9, 7);
List<Integer> playerNums = randomList(0, 9, 7);
```

Или же можно просто сгенерировать список из всех допустимых значений (от 0 до 9), перемешать его используя `Collections.shuffle`, а затем взять нужное количество элементов и отсортировать его.

```java
public static List<Integer> randomList(int min, int maxIncl, int count) {
    List<Integer> allNums = IntStream.rangeClosed(min, maxIncl)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(allNums);

    return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(count, allNums.size())) // индексы
        .mapToObj(allNums::get) // Stream<Integer>
        .sorted()       // сортировать по возрастанию
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерировать список примерно так:

```
var list = new Random().ints(0, 10).limit(7).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Напечатать в консоль сортированый список в обратном порядке:

```
var reverseSortedList = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList())
System.out.println(reverseSortedList);
```

Comment: В данном случае  возможны дубликаты. Надо  увеличить количество итераций, и выбрать уникальные значения.

Comment: @Труфальдино а ты еще раз вопрос перечитай и на примеры автора посмотри

Comment: хорошо,  ты самый  умный

Comment: @Труфальдино подкинул толковую мысль, но задача сейчас этого не требует, так что можно обойтись.
Но для любопытства, если не затруднит, очень хочется увидеть в коде, как избежать дубликатов.
Явно пригодится.